# Error accessing @runtimeMXBean.startTime in SpringBoot 3.1 when loading a page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have an HTML login file.
However, after upgrading SpringBoot to version 3.1, I encounter an issue where the login page fails to load.
The error appears to be related to accessing @runtimeMXBean.startTime through Thymeleaf.
It seems that SpringBoot 3.1 has enhanced its security measures and restricted access to this functionality.

The purpose of using @runtimeMXBean.startTime was to cache the browser by utilizing the server start time as a key. This was done to facilitate UI translation data.

Do you know of any possible solutions or workarounds for this problem?

Below is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
   ....
  </head>
  <body th:data-cb="${@runtimeMXBean.startTime}">
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>
    <script th:src="@{/app-lib/bundles/login.js}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the error:

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "@runtimeMXBean.startTime" (template: "login" - line 12, col 9)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 173 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "@runtimeMXBean.startTime" (template: "login" - line 12, col 9)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardDefaultAttributesTagProcessor.processDefaultAttribute(StandardDefaultAttributesTagProcessor.java:165)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardDefaultAttributesTagProcessor.process(StandardDefaultAttributesTagProcessor.java:98)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 175 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1021E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property 'startTime': 'Accessing member 'startTime' is forbidden for type 'class sun.management.RuntimeImpl' in Thymeleaf expressions. Blocked classes are: [com.sun.*, jakarta.*, java.*, javax.*, jdk.*, org.ietf.jgss.*, org.omg.*, org.w3c.dom.*, org.xml.sax.*, sun.*]. Allowed classes are: [java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Byte, java.lang.Character, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Enum, java.lang.Float, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Math, java.lang.Number, java.lang.Short, java.lang.String, java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigInteger, java.math.RoundingMode, java.time.*, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Collection, java.util.Date, java.util.Enumeration, java.util.HashMap, java.util.HashSet, java.util.Iterator, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashSet, java.util.LinkedList, java.util.List, java.util.Locale, java.util.Map, java.util.Map$Entry, java.util.Optional, java.util.Properties, java.util.Set, java.util.stream.Stream].'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:214)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:105)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:410)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
    ... 193 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.EvaluationException: Accessing member 'startTime' is forbidden for type 'class sun.management.RuntimeImpl' in Thymeleaf expressions. Blocked classes are: [com.sun.*, jakarta.*, java.*, javax.*, jdk.*, org.ietf.jgss.*, org.omg.*, org.w3c.dom.*, org.xml.sax.*, sun.*]. Allowed classes are: [java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Byte, java.lang.Character, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Enum, java.lang.Float, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Math, java.lang.Number, java.lang.Short, java.lang.String, java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigInteger, java.math.RoundingMode, java.time.*, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Collection, java.util.Date, java.util.Enumeration, java.util.HashMap, java.util.HashSet, java.util.Iterator, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashSet, java.util.LinkedList, java.util.List, java.util.Locale, java.util.Map, java.util.Map$Entry, java.util.Optional, java.util.Properties, java.util.Set, java.util.stream.Stream].
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.ThymeleafEvaluationContext$ThymeleafEvaluationContextACLPropertyAccessor.canRead(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.java:237)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:203)
    ... 199 common frames omitted
```

Do you know of any possible solutions or workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Maybe inject the runtimeMXBean into your controller and add an attribute into the Model manually?